# JQuery variable in function strange behavior

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, each, behavior

I was working on script which resizes images to fit container size. I wrote down the following code:

```
$(function () {
    $('.postbody .content img').each(function () {
        var containerWidth = $(this).parent().width();
        if ($(this).width() > containerWidth) {
            $(this).width(containerWidth);
            $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(this).attr('src') + '" target="_blank"></a>');
        }
    });
});
```

But it only worked for the first element in loop. With my previous experience with issues following assigning jQuery methods to a variable I changed the code a bit:

```
$(function (){
    $('.postbody .content img').each(function () {
        if ($(this).width() > $(this).parent().width()) {
            $(this).width( $(this).parent().width() );
            $(this).wrap('<a href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" target="_blank"></a>');
        }
    });
});
```

And now it works perfectly. But I cannot figure out how. Shouldn't the `containerWidth` variable get new value with each function call by the each loop?

EDIT: Please note that all containers are equal size.

Comment: Yeah it will get updated. But not if that particular code runs before the page got loaded.

Comment: it should work, can you create the issue in a demo.. only thing is you might have to wait for the image to get loaded

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/594e3ghn/

Comment: The above script will work fine on `$(window).load()` event. As by that time all the images are loaded. Hence the parent `div` gets it width. I think the issue is with the event and not with the variable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/594e3ghn/3/

Comment: Okay now, when I ran this in a fiddle I see that the second solution doesn't work too. It had to be my browser's cache making this appear properly.  Thanks for your help, it has been a bit confusing!

Comment: @Selenir yes.... both the snippets doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$(function () {
    $('.postbody .content').each(function () {
        var containerWidth = $(this).width();
        var img = $(this).find("img");
        if (img.width() > containerWidth) {
            img.width(containerWidth);
            img.wrap('<a href="' + img.attr('src') + '" target="_blank"></a>');
        }
    });
});
```

Or You can perform same operation simply with CSS

just make img tag max-width to 100%

Ex.

```
img {
   max-width: 100%;
}
```